# Justification for the definition of A/R using the power set axiom

Tags: first-order-logic, axioms

I'm currently doing a question from the Foundations of Mathematics written by Kenneth Kunen for self-teaching purposes, and I'm currently stuck on a question that asks me to justify the definition of A/R using the power set axiom and not the replacement axiom.

The steps I have done so far (and I'm not sure if I've done them correctly to be honest) are as follows:

We are given $ A/R \subseteq P(A) $

$ [x] $ is defined as $ [x] = \{ y \in A \wedge y R x\}$ and the Power set is defined as $ P(x) = \{x: x \subseteq A \} $

$\forall x \in A/R \rightarrow x \in P(A) $ as $A/R \subseteq P(A)$

$x$ is then a subset for which $\forall a \in x \rightarrow a \in A$ as $x \in P(A)$

$[x] \in A/R \rightarrow [x] \in P(A) $ by definition

Which leads to $\forall y \in [x] \rightarrow y \in A $ as $[x] \in P(A)$

From here I'm lost as to how to proceed. I think I can use restricted comprehension to prove that the set containing [x] exists since I have one condition fulfilled as $[x] \in P(A)$, but I don't know what the corresponding property would be. Any pointers or critics (regarding proof or structuring of question) would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You need to ensure $R\neq 0$ before you can divide by it.

Comment: @Michael sorry for the misunderstanding but A/R is referring to the set of equivalence classes instead of division.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have Kunen's book to hand. I take it that $A/R$ is intended to represent the set of equivalence classes of the (equivalence) relation $R$ on a set $A$. Then you have:

$$
A/R = \{ C \in P(A) : \exists x \in A . \forall y . (y \in C \Leftrightarrow x \mathrel{R} y)\}
$$

I.e., $A/R$ comprises all sets $C$ that, for some $x$, comprise precisely the elements $y$ that are equivalent under $R$ to $x$.

The power set axiom and the axiom of comprehension (which Kunen may be calling restricted comprehension) imply the existence of the set on the right-hand side of the above equation - the replacement axiom is not required.

Comment: Thank you answering! How Kunen defines A/R is $A/R = \{ [x] : x \in A \}$. I guess what I'm lost on is how to proceed using comprehension in the steps provided in the question given the definition put forward by Kunen. 

From looking at your answer, it would seem like the Power Set is used as the pre-defined set that justifies the existence of C in the restricted comprehension axiom. From there, I assume the corresponding property is the relation between x and y $x R y$. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I think you need to look at Kunen's definition of $[x]$. I think you'll find it's $\{y \in A : x\mathrel{R}y\}$: if so,his definition of $A / R$ and mine are equivalent.